# Ker of the Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

Can anyone please confirm that the Kernel of the Fourier transform is the zero function?
I have the 'intuition' that it is the case, because a signal with no frequency can't be non-zero

I would need confirmation because I have an equation $\int_R\Phi(k)e^{ikx}dk=0$ ... is it tantamount to $\Phi=0$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is $R$? What integral are we dealing with (Riemann or Lebesgue)? And what are the conditions on $\Phi$ (integrable, continuous, etc.)?

Comment: In brief, "yes, the kernel is $0$", but the details depend on your context. Can you clarify?

Comment: Hi $\Phi$ is continuous and R is all the real numbers (from $-\infty$ to $\infty$)

Comment: This should follow immediately from the inverse Fourier transform.